# Get the git repo in my production site to my testing environment

Tags: git, github, push, git-merge, pull

I just took over someone's project and I am not completely certain of how she set up her system. We have three set ups: a)My testing environment, and two remote systems `systemAlpha` and `systemBeta`. For the website `alpha` is the production(live) site and `beta` is the repo site, which means I can take changes done in my testing site and send them to `beta` before comiting the live changes in `alpha`

The problem I am having is the when I do `git log` in alpha the last commit is `ce14507a77...` followed by `b6994fb976...` while in `beta` the last commit is `b6994fb976...`. When I clone `Alpha` into my testing environment is only cloning up to `b6994fb976...` and not `ce14507a77...`. What I want to know is:

1.) How can I clone the `alpha` to my testing environment up to the latest commit `ce14507a77...`?
2.) How can I make sure `beta` points to the latest commit `ce14507a77...` and not `b6994fb976...`?

Another piece of information that I can give you is this

```
root# cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/dev 
b8855f28e
root# cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
root# cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master 
b6994fb976
```

I am guessing fixing 2) will fix 1) but I am stuck. I am new to Git so if you need further information like `remote.origin.fetch`, `core.bare`, `remote.origin.url` I can add it, I just did not wanted to give unnecessary information. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add this information when I do `git status` in `alpha`

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
```

Comment: First of all, what does this all have to do with SVN?

Comment: It was a suggested tag, I removed it so there is no confusion. Thank you

Comment: Well, it’s not just the tag, it is also mentioned in your text…

Comment: It's evidently just about Git so I edited the post to clarify :)